# Why I can't see my teams while creating StoreKit Configuration File

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am trying to add In-app purchases to my app. I tried to create StoreKit Configuration File but after checking "Sync this file with an app in App Store Connect" I wanted to pick my team but the only options I had were "None" or "Add an account...". And answering upcoming question: Yes I have team.[image: Here is screenshot of adding the file]

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had multiple teams set up and the first one (an old one I wasn't using much) had its login expired. I removed that and the team dropdown in sync configuration populated correctly

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove or sign in again Apple Developer account which have error. Here, **Xcode -> Settings -> tab Account**

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your Apple Developer Account into Xcode from Settings -> tab Accounts
or just click "Add an account" button

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, yes I’ve done it and I have even more than one.

Comment: @green8 then you need to check if your account role is eligible to edit IAP, it should be Admin or App Manager. [More details](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/)

Comment: Yes it is my account so I am account holder, admin, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that apple id you are using has Admin role of app on app store connect.